# Yii2 ignore first database result

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2

is there any way to ignore the first result record in Yii2 at a query? I have a list of numbers that represents a client. For designing purposes i had to query the first record separatly but now i have it duplicated. My questin is how can I query in Yii2 to ignore the first result?

Regards,
Gábor

The second find is the query where i need to ignore the first result:
public function actionGeneratePage() {

public function actionGeneratePage() {

```
    $behivott = Sorszam::find()->with('ablak')
        ->orderBy(['behivas_datum' => SORT_DESC])
        ->limit(1)
        ->all();
    $sorszamok = Sorszam::find()->with('ablak')
        ->orderBy(['behivas_datum' => SORT_DESC])
        ->limit(4)
        ->all();
    $reklam = Reklam::find()->all();

    return $this->render('generatePage', [
        'sorszamok' => $sorszamok,
        'reklam'    => $reklam,
        'behivott'  => $behivott,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the primary key of the first record? If so you can just add a condition to exclude it from the query.

Comment: Yes but the list queries 4 records orderd by a timestamp and i need to ignore the freshest every time.

Comment: Add the code you are using for the second query.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [`offset()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#offset()-detail) to skip the first record:

```
$sorszamok = Sorszam::find()->with('ablak')
    ->orderBy(['behivas_datum' => SORT_DESC])
    ->limit(4)
    ->offset(1)
    ->all();
```

Also you can use a single query to get both `$behivott` and `$sorszamok` with [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php):

```
$sorszamok = Sorszam::find()->with('ablak')
    ->orderBy(['behivas_datum' => SORT_DESC])
    ->limit(5)
    ->all();

$behivott = array_shift($sorszamok);
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with a more database efficient solution.